# How can I test the Lipschitz condition for a second order system?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I have the second order autonomous system

$$x_1 '= ax_1 - bx_1x_2
\\
x_2 '= -cx_2 + dx_1x_2$$

How can I apply the Lipschitz condition to this second order system?

Can anyone explain step by step how to apply the condition in this case?

Regards

Keiver

Comment: In short, the right sides are continuously differentiable (and more), and thus locally Lipschitz. This is sufficient for local existence and global uniqueness. To guarantee existence for all times, you need to prove boundedness, which for the Volterra-Lotka predator-prey system follows from the existence and shape of its first integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: You can write the right hand side of the system as:

$$f(x,y)= (ax-bxy,-cy+dxy)^T$$

Think about what the Lipschitz condition means for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Remember that in the one variable case, it suffices to check that $\bigg{|}\cfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg{|}\leq L_0$ on some compact and convex set $D_0$, i.e. the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is bounded on some subset of the real line. This follows from the mean value theorem (MVT), as you can check.

Now for two variables, what is the derivative of $f$ with respect to the vector $(x,y)^T$? This is the Jacobian matrix.

To show that $f$ is Lipschitz, it is sufficient to find a uniform bound given your favorite norm of the Jacobian matrix. Any two norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent, so you're free to choose any norm.

Computint the Jacobian we get:

$$Df(x)=\begin{pmatrix}a-by&-bx \\ dy &-c+dx \end{pmatrix} $$

Now use this to find a uniform bound for $Df$. Another hint is to recall the definition of the operator norm of $A:E \rightarrow F$:

$$||A|| = \sup_{||x||_{E}=1}{||A(x)||_{F}}$$

Here, $E$ and $F$ are the the "source" and "target" vector spaces of the operator $A$, which in this case are both $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Pick any matrix (as an operator on $\mathbb{R}^2$) norm you want to find a suitable upper bound, e.g. the $\ell_1$ matrix norm. That is, $$||A||_{\ell_1}= \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \sum_{i=1}^{m}|a_{ij}|$$

This is the maximum value of the sum of absolute values of the columns of $A$. Analogously, you can define the $\ell_{\infty}$ matrix norm as the maximum value of the sum of absolute values of the rows of $A$.

I hope this helps in at least getting started. You should be able to take it from here.

Note: The function may not be globally Lipschitz, but only locally Lipschitz. In other words, it is Lipschitz only on some open and connected set $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Then, which is the absolute value for Jacobian Matrix |Df(x)| ? Is like this: |A|=√ (A^T*A) ? or just is calculate the determinant?